# Woman exploring a cave has a creature jump into her face and control her

Tags: story-identification, movie

A woman is in a cave exploring and comes across an object (it may be a large stone).  She picks up the object to look at it and a creature or something jumps out of the object into her face.

She is under control of this creature.  The movie goes on and I missed how this happened but these membrane creatures come into the picture.  The membranes are fixed in place in some building but open and close like they are breathing.   People fear them.  I didn't find out why they were feared.  I saw this movie in the 70s or 80s.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was it a current movie when you saw it, or an old movie (e.g. 50s or 60s)?  Did you see it in the theatre or on TV?  What country and language was it in?

Comment: Was that some kind of parasite inside the body or head?

Comment: I watched this movie in the 80s.

Comment: I saw this movie in the 80s in Columbus, Ohio on TV.   The thing that jumped into the girls face looked very briefly like a dragon head but was etherial (like a ghost).  It did no physical harm to her face.

Comment: Alien 2: On Earth (1980) looks close.  I don't remember so much gore.  I'm going to find the movie and watch it.  I'll let you know.

Comment: It's looking like a strong possibility that Alien 2: On Earth (1980) is the movie.

Comment: Alien 2: On Earth (1980) was the movie where spelunkers go into a cave and find a rock with alien life.  Thanks for everyone's help on this one!

Comment: If it answers your question, please post it in the answer section.

Answer (score 5):

[Alien 2: On Earth](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078749/) (1980) was the movie where spelunkers go into a cave and find a rock with alien life. Thanks for everyone's help on this one!

Quoting from the [plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_2:_On_Earth#Plot) on Wikipedia:

> Thelma and her husband Roy meet up with their friends for **a trip to explore a cave.** The group stops at a roadside café to buy food and change into their caving gear. Thelma's friend Burt discovers a blue rock that he decides to keep in his pack.
>
> The group arrives at the cave, and quickly rappels to the bottom to set up camp for the night. Before falling asleep, Thelma tells Roy that she feels that something horrible is about to happen, but Roy calms her down.
>
> The next day, Thelma's friend **Jill discovers the blue rock that Burt found appears to be pulsating. The rock opens up and a creature attacks her face.** Thelma witnesses the attack and panics. Roy calms her down, then decides to go find Jill's body.

Comment: Important to note here that despite use of "Alien 2" in the title, this movie had no actual connection to the original Ridley Scott *Alien* from 1979.  Just proof how fast a cheap knock-off can be produced...